# how to add a script to objects in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried everything online the class name is the same as the file name but I keep getting this error, and also the console is also giving me nothing.

[image]

[image]

Unity version: **2019.2.12f1**

this error appeared when trying to add script to object :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urmBH.png)

Comment: as Chev explains, simply (1) delete the file (2) start again, but *the file name must be the same as the class name*

Comment: Also try a name OTHER THAN "Player". there may be some weird conflict.  Try "SedPlayer" or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

OK, what this probably means is that the filename and class name are different - this happens when you rename files outside unity and always recommend you rename within Unity and keep the class name and file name in sync.

Check that the class name, `Player`, matches the file name and also refresh the folder within unity:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Not to overstate the obvious, also confirm you have no compilations errors in your console. Access the console via window -> console

Comment: i did as you told me and i double cheked but no success i keep getting the same error

Comment: Then you can a script compilation error. Open the Unity console: window > console and check that you do not have errors in the script when you try to start the game. Let me know if that is the issue and I will update the answer for others.

Comment: Don't share the code - just confirm there are no compilation errors in your console as per the comment above

Comment: there is no error and the console shows nothing (check the image in the answer)

Comment: There is an error - it cannot find the asset. Unity keeps track of assets internally so not good to manage the filesystem outside of unity. You can also try Assets > Reimport, but probably best to just delete, save then create another